# division and reminder in prolog without mathematical built-in predicates

Tags: prolog, division, predicate

I am trying to build the division predicate from scratch in prolog, dvd(A,B,C), C=B/A. without using the predicate div?
also for the remainder.

Comment: The way you have described it, it is almost impossible. You need to refine your question a bit to include more of the text of the original homework statement. Is this about successor arithmetic?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty doable.
Here `'is'` is the key in solving division and remainder.

**For Division:**
'/' is used for dividing two numbers.

```
division(A,B,C):-
    C is B/A.
```

**For Remainder:**
Here 'mod' between numbers gives the remainder.

```
remainder(A,B,C):-
    C is B mod A.
```

**Example:-**

```
?-division(2,6,Answer).
Answer = 3
?-remainder(2,6,Answer).
Answer = 0

?-division(2,5,Answer).
Answer = 2.5
?-remainder(2,5,Answer).
Answer = 1
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't / considered as a built-in predicate?

Comment: div(A,B) is a built-in predicate https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?function=div/2

Comment: But an operator may well (and in this case _is_) a built-in, just written differently.

Comment: You are confused about what "operator" means in Prolog. If you read the documentation you linked yourself, you will know that div/2 is an arithmetic function (and it is **not** a predicate!). It is also declared as an operator, but this has relevance for the parsing of the Prolog source code by the compiler.

Comment: ok, I get it, div is built-in arithmetic function.

Comment: There are only "built-in" arithmetic functions. In SWI-Prolog, they are all implemented by the is/2 predicate, which is basically a mini-language interpreter for arithmetic expressions.